# Detecting generation transactions

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I'm implementing my own blockchain reader but I'm stuck validating transactions.

I can validate a common transaction checking the UTXO and executing both scripts, but... how do I validate generation transactions? AFAIK there's no flag that lets me detect generation so I can ignore the input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eligius pool and 'generated' bitcoins](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/209/eligius-pool-and-generated-bitcoins)

Comment: @cdecker IMHO it's not a duplicate, even if the answer overlaps. That question asks *what* are generated transactions, this one asks *how* to detect them. Different questions. I'd keep this one for reference.

Comment: Sure, I'll retract the close flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify the response from kaoD for future reference. The generation transaction is a transaction with exactly 1 input, whose prevOut hash is null:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

An example of such a transaction in JSON format can be found [here](http://blockexplorer.com/rawtx/7dea68bf5b470747c1d821ac6e223e0d8ad611f51ddba0de4977834d3aedda02) (blockchain.info is no use here as it does not conform the JSON output of `bitcoind`). Notice that besides this, the Satoshi client also puts the coinbase transaction in first position in the `tx` array, I wouldn't trust this too much though as it may well change in future and may not be consistent across clients.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, [found it](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/209/eligius-pool-and-generated-bitcoins):

> In main.h, function IsCoinBase(): return (vin.size() == 1 && vin[0].prevout.IsNull());